# htaccess 301 redirect certain URL pattern

Tags: url, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect: `http://site.com/FOO/BAR/BAZ`

to `http://site.com/FOO/NEW/BAZ`

so, subsitute the second segment in my URL with a new one.

ideally I'd like to use HTACCESS and a 301 as these pages have permanently moved.

The URL structure will not change. Ideally there won't be a query string, but doesn't matter too much is there is.

thanks

*8EDIT** - I should clarify and say that "BAR" is not a wildcard - it is one word. the real life example is:

old Links: `site.com/events/details/XXX`

new links: `site.com/events/VIEW/xxx`

I don't want: `site.com/events/add-new`

to redirect. JUST if the second segment equals "details" in my case.

**further clarification**
sorry haven't been exactly clear.

Existing URL: `site.com/events/details/%wildcard%`

should redirect to `site.com/foo/view/%wildcard%`

but nothing else.

Comment: Please check the second edit in my answer. This one should work for you, I've tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this one?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^FOO/(.+)/BAZ$ FOO/NEW/BAZ [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT:** Not sure, but you may need to pass the whole address, here's another sample of code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^FOO/(.+)/BAZ$ http://site.com/FOO/NEW/BAZ [L,R=301]
```

**2nd edit:** Here's the final solution. I've tried it today on a shared hosting and it worked well.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^FOO/(.+)/BAZ$ http://site.com/FOO/NEW/BAZ/ [L,R=301]
```

The only difference is that the last example contains a slash (`/`) at the end of the new path.

Comment: thanks, will test it now. I have slightly amended my post as well.

Comment: musta been the slash, this htaccess stuff boggles my mind. much obliged